# Is there a robust and reliable software to change the lattice vectors of unit cells?

Tags: density-functional-theory, crystallography, lammps

I am working with Heusler and Half Heusler materials on LAMMPS. Currently the study follows the properties in individual lattice directions such as [100] [110] etc. As of now, I am obtaining the unit cell coordinates from the [materials project](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-924130/#) website and replicating the atoms in the desired directions. When doing this, evaluating the properties in directions such as [110] or [111] require a tremendous effort to ensure that the periodicity etc. is retained.

Instead, is there a way to determine the orthogonal unit cell with a specific rotation applied to it? For example, to determine the unit cell with the x axis set in [111] direction such that using the atomic coordinates in LAMMPS is made easier and more straightforward?

** I have read the reply for [this post](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2417/lattice-representation-change-of-unit-cell) but that did not properly answer my question.

Comment: Did you try VESTA or atomsk, atomsk can rotate unit cell and find periodicity by giving angle.

Comment: @Pranavkumar thanks for the suggestion. No I have not tried either. I shall try atomsk and see if that works. What is the process with VESTA?

Comment: VESTA>EDIT>put_rotation_matrix

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Answer by Pranav Kumar](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9554/is-there-a-robust-and-reliable-software-to-change-the-lattice-vectors-of-unit-ce#comment19917_9554):

> "VESTA>EDIT>put_rotation_matrix"

[Worked for the author of the question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9554/is-there-a-robust-and-reliable-software-to-change-the-lattice-vectors-of-unit-ce#comment19919_9554):

> "Thank you. It worked."